# Doublets of a user in view member list

Tags: views, users

I have created a created a list in view of all members and so far it´s working fine.

I use both User profile and Profile 2.

- The user profile for information the member are allowed to edit.
- A Profile 2 type for information they are not allowed to edit but should be visible in the view list.

But I notice that if I create a profile type in Profile 2, View make doublets of the member. If I have two profile types, I get doublets, if I make 3 profile types, I get triplets of a member in the list.

Is there any way I can use more than one profile type without having the same member appearing in the list several times?

Comment: Aggregation. [Remove Duplicate Views Results](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/duplicate-views-results/)